# Why does ExtJS make so many GET requests

Tags: extjs

All I have is one graph / chart, and some tooltips by ExtJS on my website. Why does it have to make between 400 and 600 requests to my server just to load that? It's making calls to a zillion different .js files...

```
clickrepeater.js
manager.js
seperator.js
offset.js
button.js
textmetrics.js
item.js
box.js
auto.js
```

And that's just to name a FEW. On a slow connection, these requests take as long as 30 seconds to complete! And yet, I only have just the one production ext.js referenced by my html code. It's ext.js that's making all these additional requests.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're running it in development mode where it loads each source file individually for ease of debugging (and some other things). You need to make a production build using [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) which will concat all the required parts of the framework + your app into a single file.

Comment: I'm using the extjs-debug.js instead of the ext.js, because I have no choice, because there is a bug in ext.js and it's broken, as indicated by extjs forum staff at: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264887-Ext-4.2.1-Commercial-Ext.cmd-missing-in-Ext.js-file

Comment: You can include `ext-all.js`, which is the full lib minified and compressed.

Comment: Also, you should probably still be able to make a build using `ext-debug` anyway. Have you tried?